# how does the traitsui object model work

Tags: python, traits, enthought, traitsui

Can someone explain why this code crashes?  What I think should happen is that it should not crash if it is using fully qualified trait names, which it is in this case.

```
from traits.api import *
from traitsui.api import *

class Struct(HasTraits): pass

class Struct1(Struct):
  some_data=Int(4)
  some_more_data=Str('pizza')

class Struct2(Struct):
  some_data=Int(5)
  some_more_data=Str('wossar')

class Subwindow(Handler):
  struct1=Instance(Struct1)
  struct2=Instance(Struct2)

  which_struct=Enum(1,2)
  cur_struct=Any

  def _struct1_default(self): return Struct1()
  def _struct2_default(self): return Struct2()
  def _cur_struct(self): return self.struct1

  @on_trait_change('which_struct')
  def switch_views(self): NotImplemented #switch views here

traits_view=View(
    Item(name='which_struct'),
    Item(name='object.cur_struct.some_data'),
    Item(name='object.cur_struct.some_more_data'),
)

Subwindow().configure_traits()
```

When I run this, I get

```
AttributeError: 'Subwindow' object has no attribute 'object.cur_struct.some_data'
```

but it does, if you inspect the object.

I was fiddling with this example and I made it work correctly if I replace `cur_struct` with a `Property` trait, and I don't know why. However, that isn't feasible for my real application, where another class listens for events from an entirely different class and switches `cur_struct`.

Comment: Your traceback says `InteractiveSubwindow`, but that appears nowhere in the code you have quoted. Please correct your example such that it runs and gives the error you are asking about. Thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry, its just subwindow.  The simpler example gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, don't use `Item(name=...)`. Just pass the name as the first positional argument. The constructor does some special processing on the value passed to it before assigning it to the `name` trait. Explicitly using `name` is only used internally when we need to avoid that processing.